# Passing Template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I am trying to understand templates better

I have a template class that starts like this in my .h:

```
template <class DOC_POLICY, class PRINT_POLICY, class UNDO_POLICY>
class CP_EXPORT CP_Application : public CP_Application_Imp
```

Now I need to initialize so in my .cpp so I do:

```
CPLAT::CP_DocumentPolicy_None * d = new CPLAT::CP_DocumentPolicy_None();
CPLAT::CP_PrintPolicy_None * p = new CPLAT::CP_PrintPolicy_None();
CPLAT::CP_UndoPolicy_None * u = new CPLAT::CP_UndoPolicy_None();

CPLAT::CP_Application::Init(d, p, u);
```

I get an error on CPLAT::CP_Application::Init(d, p, u); that states:

error: 'template class CPLAT::CP_Application' used without template parameters

How does one pass template parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should work

```
CPLAT::CP_Application<CPLAT::CP_DocumentPolicy_None,CPLAT::CP_PrintPolicy_None,CPLAT::CP_UndoPolicy_None>::Init(d,p,u);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a ***class template***, not a "template class". It's a template from which classes can be generated. (There's also *function templates*. Those are templates from which functions are generated.)
2. It takes ***type parameters***. `d`, `p`, and `u` are (pointers to) objects, not types. Types are, for example, `CPLAT::CP_DocumentPolicy_None`, `CPLAT::CP_PrintPolicy_None`, and `CPLAT::CP_UndoPolicy_None`.
   So you should be able to do

   ```
   CP_Application< CPLAT::CP_DocumentPolicy_None
                 , CPLAT::CP_PrintPolicy_None
                 , CPLAT::CP_UndoPolicy_None > app;
   ```
3. When you have function templates, where *template parameters* are also *function parameters* (they appear as types in the function's argument list), you can omit them in the list of actual template arguments when instantiating the template:

   ```
   template< typename T >
   void f(T obj) {...}
   ...
   f(42); // same as f<int>(42), because 42 is of type int
   ```

   This is automatic function argument deduction.
4. Instead of having to call an `Init` member function, have the constructor initialize the object.